# How can i build a group with three inputs in form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to check 3 inputs for my Football bet game example. It works but I have more than 3 inputs in my form. I want to check a **MINIMUM** of 3 inputs.

The Group of three inputs consists of two type="text" field and one type=checkbox.

Here are my HTML Code:

```
<form id="AddTip" onsubmit="return chkAddTip()" action="Ctipservlet" method="POST">
    <h1>Bet the Games</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Playtime</th> <th>Games</th><th>Your bets</th><th>Confirmation</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20:00 pm</td>
            <td>Dortmund - Bayern</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_a0" maxlength="2" size="2">:<input type="text" name="team_b0" maxlength="2" size="2"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:00 pm</td>
            <td>Dortmund - Schalke</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_a1" maxlength="2" size="2">:<input type="text" name="team_b1" maxlength="2" size="2"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="tip" value="Get your bet">
    <input type="submit" onclick="this.form.onsubmit = null" name="back" value="Back">
```

And here my JavaScript Function:

```
function chkAddTip(){
    var inputs = document.getElementById('AddTip').getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 3){
        if (inputs[i].type !== "submit" && (!inputs[i].value || !inputs[i + 1].value || !inputs[i + 2].checked)){
            alert("Bitte deinen Tipp und die Bestättigung abgeben.")
            inputs[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean flag that you set to `true` when a valid bet is found. Exit the loop as soon as this flag is set to `true`. After the loop, do what's needed depending on the flag's value.

```
function chkAddTip(){
    var inputs = document.getElementById('AddTip').getElementsByTagName('input');

    // boolean flag
    var foundValid = false;

    // early exit the loop if at least one valid bet has been found
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length && !foundValid; i += 3){
        if (inputs[i].type !== "submit" && (inputs[i].value && inputs[i + 1].value && inputs[i + 2].checked)) {
            // set the flag to true when a valid bet is found
            foundValid = true;
        }
    }

    // determine the return value depending on the flag
    if (foundValid) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Bitte deinen Tipp und die Bestättigung abgeben.")
        inputs[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me if the user use the group ( 2 inputs field + one checkbox) and more than one checkbox. then get a error message